# Parsing co-ordinate values in a JSON file and extract their corresponding attribute value

Tags: python, json, parsing, openstreetmap

I have this JSON in a file:

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "generator": "overpass-turbo",
  "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.",
  "timestamp": "2017-02-23T15:12:02Z",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "relation/2264913",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "relation/2264913",
        "admin_level": "10",
        "boundary": "administrative",
        "name": "ABC",
        "type": "boundary"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12.0397449,
              51.6438084
            ],
            [
              12.0388557,
              51.6403582
            ],
            [
              12.0413471,
              51.640221
            ],
            [
              12.0405388,
              51.6377118
            ],
            [
              12.0423344,
              51.6374845
            ],
            [
              12.0419595,
              51.6343258
            ],
            [
              12.0804867,
              51.6295502
            ],
            [
              12.0698061,
              51.6438756
            ],
            [
              12.0681545,
              51.6437836
            ],
            [
              12.0658655,
              51.6436203
            ],
            [
              12.0632812,
              51.6438909
            ],
            [
              12.0627055,
              51.6442096
            ],
            [
              12.063009,
              51.6448326
            ],
            [
              12.0574821,
              51.6445929
            ],
            [
              12.0557545,
              51.6445538
            ],
            [
              12.0519454,
              51.6441561
            ],
            [
              12.0475772,
              51.6440126
            ],
            [
              12.0397449,
              51.6438084
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "relation/6249468",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "relation/6249468",
        "landuse": "farmland",
        "type": "multipolygon"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              12.0473976,
              51.6439141
            ],
            [
              12.0505144,
              51.6439299
            ],
            [
              12.0511152,
              51.6439698
            ],
            [
              12.0516503,
              51.6439931
            ],
            [
              12.0523275,
              51.6440464
            ],
            [
              12.0534621,
              51.6441396
            ],
            [
              12.053843,
              51.6441854
            ],
            [
              12.0543982,
              51.6442436
            ],
            [
              12.0545672,
              51.6442727
            ],
            [
              12.0553759,
              51.6444417
            ],
            [
              12.0554563,
              51.6444667
            ],
            [
              12.055522,
              51.6445033
            ],
            [
              12.0555596,
              51.6445424
            ],
            [
              12.0555851,
              51.6445981
            ],
            [
              12.0556065,
              51.6447213
            ],
            [
              12.0556333,
              51.6448386
            ],
            [
              12.0556588,
              51.6449244
            ],
            [
              12.0557084,
              51.6450334
            ],
            [
              12.055738,
              51.6451124
            ],
            [
              12.0558023,
              51.6453355
            ],
            [
              12.0558868,
              51.645531
            ],
            [
              12.0561852,
              51.645526
            ],
            [
              12.0565098,
              51.6455568
            ],
            [
              12.0570207,
              51.6456001
            ],
            [
              12.0572956,
              51.6456126
            ],
            [
              12.0574405,
              51.6456276
            ],
            [
              12.0575451,
              51.6456534
            ],
            [
              12.057643,
              51.6456966
            ],
            [
              12.057706,
              51.6457466
            ],
            [
              12.0577463,
              51.6458015
            ],
            [
              12.0577744,
              51.6458622
            ],
            [
              12.0577905,
              51.6459288
            ],
            [
              12.0577959,
              51.6459962
            ],
            [
              12.0577851,
              51.6460736
            ],
            [
              12.0577382,
              51.6461768
            ],
            [
              12.057352,
              51.6466353
            ],
            [
              12.0572889,
              51.6467169
            ],
            [
              12.0572313,
              51.6468076
            ],
            [
              12.056904,
              51.6475399
            ],
            [
              12.0566519,
              51.6475282
            ],
            [
              12.0563327,
              51.6474841
            ],
            [
              12.0559586,
              51.6473984
            ],
            [
              12.0556649,
              51.6473202
            ],
            [
              12.0555509,
              51.6472811
            ],
            [
              12.0554449,
              51.6472353
            ],
            [
              12.0553215,
              51.6471962
            ],
            [
              12.052414,
              51.6465338
            ],
            [
              12.0521485,
              51.6464814
            ],
            [
              12.0518749,
              51.6464473
            ],
            [
              12.0515061,
              51.6464065
            ],
            [
              12.0504748,
              51.6462933
            ],
            [
              12.0499759,
              51.6462484
            ],
            [
              12.0495588,
              51.6462309
            ],
            [
              12.049127,
              51.6462193
            ],
            [
              12.0486402,
              51.6461959
            ],
            [
              12.048506,
              51.646166
            ],
            [
              12.0485168,
              51.645898
            ],
            [
              12.0485597,
              51.6457915
            ],
            [
              12.0485396,
              51.6457349
            ],
            [
              12.0484712,
              51.645695
            ],
            [
              12.0484256,
              51.6456351
            ],
            [
              12.0484149,
              51.6453296
            ],
            [
              12.0483988,
              51.6450326
            ],
            [
              12.0483693,
              51.6450109
            ],
            [
              12.0482714,
              51.6450043
            ],
            [
              12.0482767,
              51.6456018
            ],
            [
              12.0483116,
              51.6465022
            ],
            [
              12.0483035,
              51.6465929
            ],
            [
              12.0482807,
              51.6466528
            ],
            [
              12.0482204,
              51.6466936
            ],
            [
              12.0481319,
              51.6467002
            ],
            [
              12.0479904,
              51.6466969
            ],
            [
              12.0472233,
              51.6466503
            ],
            [
              12.0469014,
              51.6465904
            ],
            [
              12.0457454,
              51.6462842
            ],
            [
              12.0473976,
              51.6439141
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },{
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "way/420433184",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "way/420433184",
        "@relations": [
          {
            "role": "admin_centre",
            "rel": "2264913",
            "reltags": {
              "admin_level": "10",
              "boundary": "administrative",
              "name": "ABC",
              "type": "boundary"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          12.0622848,
          51.6370034
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I have loaded the JSON file using Python as shown below:

```
  import json
     with open('data.json') as data_file:    
     data = json.load(data_file)
```

I need to find the corresponding "@id" attribute for each of the co-ordinates inputs.

Example:

```
    Latitude           Longitude          Element ID (need to found)

 1.  12.0534621          51.6441396             6249468    
 2.  12.0473976          51.6439141             6249468    
 3.  12.0622848          51.6370034             420433184
```

.
  .
  .

How do I get the attribute values of the corresponding latitude and longitude? How do you do it iteratively if you have some 100 or more rows of latitude and longitude?

Any help would be really helpful :)

Comment: Where does 420433184 come from?

Comment: @Goyo , I'm sorry. I thought it was pasted, I have updated in the file above.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Goyo, JSON is updated now. Sry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map this function over the list of lat/longs to get a list of all the id's heres the updated code works by considering polygon vs point:

```
def get_element_id(latitude, longtitude):
  "checks each object for lat/long returns objects id or -1 if not found"

  # some helper lambda functions
  check_coords = lambda arr: [latitude, longtitude] in arr
  get_curr_id = lambda obj: obj["properties"]["@id"].split("/")[1]

  # since features is an array of 2d arrays
  for obj in data["features"]:

    obj_type = obj["geometry"]["type"]
    curr_arr = obj["geometry"]["coordinates"]

    if(obj_type == "Polygon"):
      if(any(map(check_coords, curr_arr))):
        return get_curr_id(obj)

    if(obj_type == "Point"):
      if(check_coords([curr_arr]):
        return get_curr_id(obj)

  # lat/long not found
  return -1

print get_element_id(12.0397449, 51.6438084) # prints 2264913
print get_element_id(12.0658655, 51.6436203) # prints 2264913
print get_element_id(12.052414, 51.6465338)  # prints 6249468
print get_element_id(12.0622848, 51.6370034) # prints 420433184
```

Comment: The code gives a type error as shown:
> TypeError: string indices must be integers.

Comment: I tried some work around on your code:

`if([['12.0536248', '51.6494046']] in data["features"][1]["geometry"]["coordinates"]):
       print("The coordinates is there")
else:
       print("The coordinates not working")`

But the if condition fails. Can you suggest why?

Comment: thats because you updated the json, but quick question the last `geometry` key in your json is it suppose to be a 1d array ?? The values for `geometry` key are inconsistent is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal there are mixed geometries, [two polygons and a point](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:anonymous/0a7d1b59a0126b638a96fe1cbd50920b). [Point](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.2) geometries are positions `[x, y]`. [Polygon](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.6)  geometries are lists of linear rings where each linear ring is a list of positions.

Comment: that makes much more sense

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal  As, Goyo said it as mixed geometry. In the first case I had updated a wrong one and due to data confidentiality, I had to generate a new set of GeoJSON. Sorry I am new to this domain, seeing the ID in the same structure thought I could retrieve. Please let me know if there is any other approach. Thanks both of you :)

Comment: @NMS i believe the new updated code i have solves the problem.

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal..Yes it works. Thank you so much :)